# Proof on equivalence relations help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

If $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb Z$ by $a\sim b$ iff $ab ≥ 0$. Is $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z$?

> Proof:
>
> **Reflexive:**
>   Suppose $a\in\mathbb Z$. Then $a \times a = a^2$, which is an integer $≥ 0$.
>   Thus $a\sim a$.
>
> **Symmetric:**
>   Suppose $a,b \in\mathbb Z$ and $a\sim b$. Then $ab$ is a positive integer.
>   So $ba$ is a positive integer.
>   Thus $b\sim a$.
>
> **Transitive:**
>   Suppose $a,b,c \in\mathbb Z$. Then $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ where $ab$ and $bc$ are positive integers.

My teacher told us that this is not an equivalence relation, but I am not sure how to show how it fails in the transitive proof.

Comment: $-1\sim 0$ and $0\sim 1$ but it is not true $-1\sim 1$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of transitivity is not quite right. You should start with the assumption that $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, and then use this assumption to show that $a\sim c$ (if it is true).

But in this case, as janmarqz pointed out, $-1\sim 0$ and $0\sim 1$, but $-1\not\sim 1$. So transitivity fails.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the definition of $\sim$ implies that $a\sim0$ and $0\sim b$ for any $a,b\in S$. What would transitivity imply then? (By the way, your proof that $\sim$ is symmetric is not quite right. $a\sim b$ implies that $ab$ is a non-negative integer. It doesn't imply that $ab$ is a positive integer.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the relation ~ specified been specified as $ab > 0$ , this would have very well been an equivalence relation. The equality sign forces one to consider the possibility of one of the quantities being = 0.

As pointed out in the above answer, transitivity fails